# Android Short[] to byte[] AudioRecorder is loosing frames and playback is fast

Tags: android, sockets, byte, audio-recording, short

I am working on a project which requires to send Audio frames from client to server whenever the speech is detected. The client is android app and the server is a simple python script. I am using socket to transfer my data between them. The whole project works well except the audio quality. The Audio received is a fast from the audio sent. If i send 30 sec audio from the client only 20 sec audio is received. Later on i added a simple line to check the sent and received byte length and i could notice a lot of frames missing on the receiving side. What am i doing wrong?

**Android Client**

```
@Override
    public void run() {
        new Thread(new ClientThread()).start();
        android.os.Process.setThreadPriority(android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_AUDIO);

        while (!Thread.interrupted() && isListening && audioRecord != null) {
            short[] buffer = new short[vad.getConfig().getFrameSize().getValue() * getNumberOfChannels() * 2];
            audioRecord.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);

            isSpeechDetected(buffer);
        }
    }


    private void isSpeechDetected(final short[] buffer) {
        vad.isContinuousSpeech(buffer, new VadListener() {

            @Override
            public void onSpeechDetected() {
                callback.onSpeechDetected();

                spechdet = true;
                byte[] bytes2 = new byte[buffer.length * 2];
                ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes2).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).asShortBuffer().put(buffer);
                totallen += bytes2.length;
                try {
                    os = socket.getOutputStream();
                    os.write(bytes2, 0, minBufferSize);
                }catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    s_status = false;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNoiseDetected() {
                callback.onNoiseDetected();
                if (spechdet == true) {
                    try {
                        socket.close();
                        Log.w(TAG, "total length = "+ totallen);
                    } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    spechdet = false;
                    totallen = 0;
                    new Thread(new ClientThread()).start();
                }
            }

        }
```

**Python Server**

```
import pyaudio
import socket
import select
import numpy as np
import threading, collections, queue, os, os.path
from datetime import datetime
import wave

FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 1
RATE = 16000
CHUNK = 1024

audio = pyaudio.PyAudio()
stream = audio.open(format=FORMAT, channels=CHANNELS, rate=RATE, output=True, frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)

def write_wav(filename, data):
    print("write wav %s", filename)
    wf = wave.open(filename, 'wb')
    wf.setnchannels(CHANNELS)
    assert FORMAT == pyaudio.paInt16
    wf.setsampwidth(2)
    wf.setframerate(RATE)
    wf.writeframes(data)
    wf.close()

print("recording...")


with socket.socket() as server_socket:
    server_socket.bind(('', 4444))
    server_socket.listen(5)
    wav_data = bytearray()
    while True:
        conn, address = server_socket.accept()
        print("Connection from " + address[0] + ":" + str(address[1]))

        while True:
            data = conn.recv(CHUNK)
            wav_data.extend(data)
            stream.write(data)
            if not data:
                break
        write_wav(os.path.join(datetime.now().strftime("savewav_%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S_%f.wav")), wav_data)
        print(len(wav_data))
        wav_data = bytearray()

print("finished recording")

server_socket.close()
stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
audio.terminate()
```

I am using [this](https://github.com/gkonovalov/android-vad) library to detect voice on client side and i have tried other methods on converting short[] to byte[] but results are same.

Comment: is there any way to see the lost frames?

Comment: This will be a difficult question to answer because it requires expertise in at least one of these libraries if not both, across two different languages, with limited information and without a complete reproducible example. If you'd like to increase your odds of getting an answer please consider editing your question to include a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).